# Error in Resize Images Extension Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-extensions

I'm using the resize images extension of firebase, and in some images the resize function faild with this error:
"Error when resizing image [Error: VipsJpeg: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG
VipsJpeg: out of order read at line 0
] "

Someone know about this error and how to solve it?

Thanx!